# System.Data.Entity dll not found when building project via release build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework 6.0 and I have some problems with building my project in "release" mode.

When I build project in "debug" mode - everything is fine.
But when I switch to "release" mode - EntityTypeConfiguration class becomes unacessible.
and System.Data.Entity namespace could not be found.

Any ideas how to make project work in release mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your reference path is broken but you already have the DLL in the Debug folder hence the successful build.

You can verify by looking at the properties of your reference in the solution explorer to Entity Framework and see if the Path that is specified in Properties actually exists

If you've added the reference manually just simply remove and re-add would normally solve this, or if your using Nuget removing and re-adding the package could fix this.

Comment: You're totally right. Thanks, that was a bit foolish mistake)